# Multi form submit function in JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have an application with multiple tabs/form that will be submitted. Instead of having separate submit function for each form I want to design one dynamic function that will submit any form with `submitFrm` class. Here is an example of my current code:

```js
$('.frmSubmit').on('submit', submitFrm);

function submitFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevnts default form submit.

  var frmID = $(this).prop("id"),
    formData = $('#' + frmID).serialize(), //or this way $(this).serialize()
    submitBtn = $(this).find(':submit');

  if (formData) {
    $('#' + frmID).find(':submit').prop('disabled', true); // Disable submit button
    // or this submitBtn.prop('disabled', true);
    
    /*
    Here is AJAX call.
    */
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmTab1" id="frmTab1" class="frmSubmit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="activ"><span class="label label-primary">Active:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="frmTab1_active" id="frmTab1_active" required>
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="code"><span class="label label-primary">Code:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frmTab1_code" id="frmTab1_code" maxlength="4" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="frmTab1_submit" id="frmTab1_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="message" class="alert message-submit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'm debating should I use `$(this)` object to `find()`, `serialize()` form data or I should use form id? Is there any difference? I'm also wondering if I use this function from multiple forms to submit data is that good practice? If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: i mean... there's no reason to get the form id if you have a direct reference to the form unless you intend to use said id for some purpose other than selecting from the dom. it makes no sense.

Comment: For example in ajax SUCCESS I can't use $(this) because I have entered different function at that point of time. So I either have to save frm object in variable or access form by id in order to do some dom manipulation. Does that makes sense?

Comment: You can use `this` in the ajax success if you really need to. You can pass it as context, or you can store it in a variable. The ID is not necessary.

Comment: Please provide example, I would like to see that. if you have  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Some url',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(obj){ // How to access `this` form reference here...

Comment: `var $form = $(this);
$.ajax({...}).done(function () {$form.remove();});` Or, alternatively, pass `this` to the `context` ajax option and use `this` inside. Or use an arrow function. Or use .bind. Plenty of ways to solve this problem, choose the one you want.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mentioned in my previous comment. Only if I save form object in variable that would be possible.

Comment: @Taplar So there is no difference in efficiency just opinions? Sounds good, thank you.

Comment: There is a performance difference if you take the id off the element, and look the element up, because it's an extra unnecessary step.  It's not a human noticeable difference, but it is performing extra work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use simply `$(this).serialize()` like :

```js
$('.frmSubmit').on('submit', submitFrm);

function submitFrm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = $(this).serialize();
  var submitBtn = $(this).find(':submit');

  if (formData) {
    submitBtn.prop('disabled', true);
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="frmTab1" id="frmTab1" class="frmSubmit" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="activ"><span class="label label-primary">Active:</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="frmTab1_active" id="frmTab1_active" required>
      <option value="0">No</option>
      <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="code"><span class="label label-primary">Code:</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frmTab1_code" id="frmTab1_code" maxlength="4" required>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <button type="submit" name="frmTab1_submit" id="frmTab1_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
      <div id="message" class="alert message-submit"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```